# VBA copy records that are between two date from multiple sheets to master sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I would like a button click to prompt users to enter a beginning and end date so it copies the data fill in this date range from 13 worksheets to a master sheet.

Example

Sheet 1 to sheet 4

- A --------------- C ----------- G
- Tag No. ----- Activities ----- Date
- 1 ------------- hhhh-----------9-Mar-17 (column G is Date Formatted)
- 2--------------dddd------------10-Mar-17

Sheet 5 to sheet 13

- A --------------- B----------- F
- Tag No.----- Activities ----- Date
- 1 ------------- hhhh-----------9-Mar-17 (column F is Date formatted)
- 2--------------dddd------------10-Mar-17

I want all data listed in column A and C in sheet 1:4 to be copied to a master sheet under column A and B and all data listed in column A and B in sheets 5-13 to be copied to the column A and B also in the master sheet. ( I want also beside column A and B in the master sheet to be a column C contains the name of the worksheet which this data are transferred.

Example

Master Sheet

- A-------------------B-----------------C
- Tag No. ------ Activities ------- Location
- hhh---------------hhhhh-------------Sheet 1
- lll--------------llllll-------------Sheet 1
- hhh-------------fffff---------------Sheet 2
  etc.

Thanks